# Can I create a project in Android and use it as a base template for future projects

Tags: android, project-template

Is it possible to create a project and add libraries such as volley, that will be used in most projects anyway and then copy this project to be used again and again as the base for all future projects?

The only issue I can see there being is with keystores but if I change all of the package names then surely this shouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `File Templates` - explained [here](https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-template-group-android-studiointellij/?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=f496435d0f-Android_Weekly_209&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-f496435d0f-337981481).

Short version: Yes. You'll need to create a new Folder iwth your desired template name in 
`{ANDROID_STUDIO_LOCATION}/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/`, create files which contain relevant information, create a folder structure & enter your desired template files.
An example can be found  on [github](https://github.com/riggaroo/android-studio-group-templates-mvp).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and that should be a good practice. [Android Boostrap](http://www.androidbootstrap.com/) doing something similar like it.

You can take a look at [base_app_android](https://github.com/RefineriaWeb/base_app_android)

Here the excerpt:

> Base skeleton structure to start every new project, based on the
>   design patters suggested by Robert C. Martin (aka Uncle Bob) on his
>   clean architecture.
>
> base_app_android is the project which we use at Refineria Web to start
>   any new Android project. It presents a structure of 3 layers, domain,
>   data and presentation; this approach has been chosen with the purpose
>   of creating an application that conducts unit testing and also allow
>   the portability between platforms, mainly iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can create it as a library and you can use it